# ASP.net MVC FrameSet x 2

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iframe, frameset-iframe

I'm trying to figure out a way for me to use a **frameset** with my **ASP.net MVC** app that allows me to have a **0px height** **iframe** on the **top** of the site (we will call it 0px iframe) and the **remaining into another iframe** (we will call it main iframe).

The meaning why I want to do this is so, in the **main iframe**, I can call the **0px iframe** and pop up a **notification** via jQuery and if the user switches pages while the notification is being shown then it **will stay there while the page loads**. Currently, doing that without an iframe causes the notification not to continue to show and **disappears once the user changes pages**.

I know this would be possible for a **normal html page** but I'm at a loss as to a way to do it for an ASP.net page.

Visual example:
[image]

Comment: No such thing as an iframeset. Did you mean an iframe, or a frameset?

Comment: Good catch. Corrected.

Comment: Ok thanks. Why would this be a problem for an asp.net page, exactly? What issue have you encountered, specifically? The end result of making a request to a server which runs asp.net is a HTML page in your browser. You describe a problem rather vaguely. A specific example and some code would make it a lot clearer.

Comment: The only way ive seen iframes being used in ASP.net MVC are **on the page** itself and not using a frameset. Since you have a **shared _layout** for an ASP.net page I cant find a way to add a frameset because of that.

Comment: There's no requirement for a shared layout page if you don't want one. There might be a workaround, but the structure isn't completely clear. Again, a worked example would help, and an explanation of what you've done so far and why it doesn't succeed.